# linux shell ,how to add variable in a `expression`?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to do some operation like this

```
for i in `ls -1 /var/tmp`
do
  zip /var/backup/$i.zip $i
done
```

now I want to change the `/var/tmp` dir to variable like this

```
    backup_dir=/var/tmp
    for i in `ls -1 ${backup_dir}`
    do
      zip /var/backup/$i.zip $i
    done
```

but ,it's a mistake way?how to do this?

Comment: Why do you think that is a mistake?

Comment: `for i in "$backup_dir"; do zip "/var/backup/$i.zip" "$i"; done`

Comment: What "mistake" you got when you ran your script?

Comment: I am stupid,just add`cd $backup_dir`above the for sentence,that's ok,thanks